# LinkedIn App Links to Wrong page from Share (works on site)

Tags: linkedin-api

This post: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/activity:6240272406754189312/

links to the correct site (https:// www. steppingblocks .com/post/37546) on linkedin.com, but it links to https: //www. steppingblocks .com/ when you click from the app. The app uses a built in browser to display it, which is what I'm thinking the issue is. (spaces inserted due to link limits)

This article was shared via the linkedin API on our site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It turns out that the Opengraph tags on the page I was linking to were incorrect.  The one that was specifically causing problems was the `og:url` tag.

It seems that the LinkedIn webpage uses the link you specify via the API, but the mobile app somehow uses the `og:url` tag to determine where to link to, and if that's wrong, the mobile app's link will be wrong.

The Facebook Opengraph Debugger can be useful to find problems: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/